# One sided Chebyshev inequality for non negative random variable

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Suppose a random variable $\xi$ satisfy

(1) $\xi\geq 0$

(2) E$\xi = 6$

(3) Var$\xi = 6$

Then what is the smallest $r$ such that P$(\xi\geq 10)\leq r$?

---

What I have done is basically ignore the first condition on $\xi$, use [one sided Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality) to get that

$$P(\xi-6\geq 4)\leq 6/22$$

Then to prove the sharpness of this bound I made the lucky guess that $\xi$ only take three values,$10$ with probability $6/22$, another value $x$ with probability $p$ and $0$ otherwise. Solving for $x$ and $p$ gives $x = 8$, $p = 9/22$. This solves the problem, but I have not used the first condition on $\xi$ at all. Is there a more systematic way to find $r$?